# 401 Error accessing Rest API passing get_cookie

Tags: spring, resttemplate

I am accessing an API which expects me to make a POST call to their Login endpoint and then make subsequent calls to get data. The call I make to their login endpoint works. But the subsequent call to get data throws a 401 error. This is the error I get

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException: 401 Unauthorized
    at org.springframework.web.client.DefaultResponseErrorHandler.handleError(DefaultResponseErrorHandler.java:91)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.handleResponseError(RestTemplate.java:615)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.doExecute(RestTemplate.java:573)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.execute(RestTemplate.java:544)
    at org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate.exchange(RestTemplate.java:465)
    at com.wsc.eventconsumer.phonex.api.InventoryServiceImpl.getProducts(InventoryServiceImpl.java:70)

Now this works fine when I use Postman and the Restlet client. I noticed that in Restlet client the GET call to the API passes a cookie that was set by the API in the login call. I tried passing the response headers from the login call in the GET request. But I still get a 401. I am using the standard resttemplate configuration.

```
<bean id="restTemplate" class="org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate"/>

HttpEntity<Credentials> entity = new HttpEntity<Credentials>(credentials, headers);
ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate.exchange(loginEndpoint, HttpMethod.POST, entity, String.class);
HttpHeaders rHeaders = response.getHeaders();

HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(rHeaders);
ResponseEntity<Product[]> response2 = restTemplate.exchange(productEndpoint, 
                HttpMethod.GET, request, Product[].class);
```